# Establecer valores que de el usuario a valores por default

Tags: vb.net

En mi sistema estoy implementando una ventana de configuración donde por ejemplo el sistema tiene una variable Z de tipo entero que tiene el valor 2 asignado. Y quiero que en la ventana de configuración el usuario pueda establecer el valor de Z a 7 por ejemplo, y que al abrir el sistema de nuevo Z siga teniendo ese mismo valor que asignó el usuario antes.

Alguna idea? No conozco de este tema.

Estoy trabajando en VB.Net

Comment: Puedes crearte una clase(por ejemplo) donde guardar los campos/datos que usas y luego serializarlos en un XML. Cuando el usuario cierre la aplicacion sus cambios permaneceran en el XML y al iniciar simplemente lees el XML. Esto es una de las mil y unas formas de hacerlo que hay.